# Como fazer uma só autenticação para duas aplicações diferentes no MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, identity

Olá, pessoal.
Tenho duas aplicações ASP.NET MVC5 no mesmo servidor, no mesmo site. Estou tentando fazer que uma só autenticação seja válida para os dois projetos. Ja setei um nome de cookie para as duas aplicações, mesmo assim não funcionou.

I'm trying to share the same login cookie to two differents MVC5 projects.

I've already set the same cookie name to both projects, but thats doesnt work.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieName = "OrienteIntegrada",
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Permite que o aplicativo valide o carimbo de segurança quando o usuário efetuar login.
                // Este é um recurso de segurança que é usado quando você altera uma senha ou adiciona um login externo à sua conta.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

As aplicações são acessadas assim:  server/teste e server/teste2;

Tenho que configurar alguma coisa no IIS ou em outra classe relacionada ao Identity?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de setar a machineKey no arquivo web.config, funcionou.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <machineKey decryptionKey="F6722806843145965513817CEBDECBB1F94808E4A6C0B2F2,IsolateApps" validationKey="C551753B0325187D1759B4FB055B44F7C5077B016C02AF674E8DE69351B69FEFD045A267308AA2DAB81B69919402D7886A6E986473EEEC9556A9003357F5ED45,IsolateApps" />
</system.web>
```